# Генерация документов по шаблону

Tags: alfresco

Добрый день!
У меня установлен Alfresco Community 4.2f  и ALVEX CE.
Тестировал способ генерации docx описанный  в Руководстве администратора ALVEX (Глава 8.). В шаблонах созданных в Microsoft Word замены переменных на заданные значения не происходит. Работают шаблоны созданные в LibreOffice Writter и сохраненные как Office Open XML. Замена происходит только в тексте, т.е. - если $ {variable} поместить в ячейку таблицы, то замена не произойдет. Подскажите пожалуйста как обойти данное неудобство? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема с офисными пакетами в том, что разные версии MS Office генерируют разный формат файлов, хотя все они называются docx. MS Office 2003, как и LibreOffice, генерирует идейно-верный XML, который отлично обрабатывается движком. MS Office 2007, как правило, работает хорошо. Все то, что после этого, уже особо не тестировалось и вполне может глючить.

Таблицы при генерации файлов категорически не поддерживаются, как и колонтитулы. Alvex использует библиотеку Apache POI. Обойти данное неудобство можно доработав движок. Дорабатывать нужно вот этот класс: https://github.com/ITDSystems/alvex-2.x/blob/master/core/documents-registers/repo/src/java/com/alvexcore/repo/documents/generation/TemplateServiceImpl.java#L194